# Laravel Check for Value from Relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laravel-eloquent-resource

I have a query that looks like this where I fetch data for various businesses in a particular location and I need to be able to tell that each business has (or does not have) a female employee.

```
    $business = Business::where('location', $location)
        ->with(['staff'])
        ->get();


        return MiniResource::collection($business);
```

My Mini Resource looks like this:

```
    return [
        'name' => $this->name,
        'location' => $this->location,
        'staff' => PersonResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('staff')),
    ];
```

This is what a sample response looks like:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "XYZ Business"
  "location": "London",
  "staff": [
    {
      "name": "Abigail",
      "gender": "f",
      "image": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxx/people/xxxx.png",
      "role": "Project Manager",
    },
    {
      "name": "Ben",
      "gender": "m",
      "image": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxx/people/xxxx.png",
      "role": "Chef",
    },
  ]
}
```

I really don't need the staff array, I just want to check that a female exists in the relation and then return something similar to this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "XYZ Business"
  "country": "USA",
  "has_female_employee": true;
}
```

Is there an eloquent way to achieve this ?

NB: In my original code I have more relations that I query but I had to limit this post to be within the scope of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only looking for male or female staff members, you can achieve it like so:

```
$someQuery->whereHas('staff', function ($query) {
    $query->where('gender', 'f');
})
```

If you want both genders, I wouldn't go through the hassle of achieving this in the query, but recommend reducing your results collection in your MiniResource:

```
return [
    'name' => $this->name,
    'location' => $this->location,
    'has_female_employee' => $this->whenLoaded('staff')->reduce(
        function ($hasFemale, $employee) {
            $hasFemale = $hasFemale || ($employee->gender === 'f'); 
            return $hasFemale;
        }, false),
];
```

Even better would be to create it as a method on your MiniResource for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like below and see

```
$business = Business::where('location', $location)
        ->with(['staff'])
        ->where('gender', 'f')
        ->get();
```

```
return [
        'name' => $this->name,
        'location' => $this->location,
        'has_female_employee' => empty($this->whenLoaded('staff')) ? false : true,
    ];
```